# Виртуальный метод при композиции

Tags: javascript, наследование, протоколы, виртуальная-функция

Объект класса с двумя методами `getOuter` и `getInner` оборачивается другим классом, имеющим такой же интерфейс, но используется не наследование а композиция, т. е. объект вкладывается внутрь другого и они должны иметь независимые поля.

Известно, что из метода `getOuter` ровно один раз вызывается метод `getInner`. Надо сделать так, чтобы вызывался `getInner` не оборачиваемого объекта, а оборачивающего. В качестве прокси используется класс `Wrapper`, от которого наследуются обрачивающие классы. Что надо в него дописать, чтобы работало соответствующим образом?

Желаемый вывод после дописывания врэппера:

```
outer
c
b
a
(<Cc><[Bb][Aa]>)
```

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 'A';
    this.a = 'a';
  }
  
  getOuter() {
    console.log('outer');
    return `(${this.getInner()})`;
  }
  
  getInner() {
    console.log('a');
    return this.x + this.a;
  }
}

var a = new A

class Wrapper {
  constructor(original) {
    this.original = original
  }
  
  getOuter() {
    return this.original.getOuter();
  }
  
  getInner() {
    return this.original.getInner();
  }
}

class B extends Wrapper {
  constructor(original) {
    super(original);
    this.x = 'B';
    this.b = 'b';
  }
  
  getInner() {
    console.log('b');
    return `[${this.x}${this.b}][${super.getInner()}]`;
  }
}

var b = new B(a);

class C extends Wrapper {
  constructor(original) {
    super(original);
    this.x = 'C';
    this.c = 'c';
  }
  
  getInner() {
    console.log('c');
    return `<${this.x}${this.c}><${super.getInner()}>`;
  }
}

var c = new C(b);

console.log(c.getOuter());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ура, кажется получилось!

Надо в `getOuter` в оборачиваемый инстанс сохранить забинженный метод `getInner` текущего класса, в когда тот вызовет `super.getInner`, то эту ссылку затереть и продолжить вызывать по цепочке:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 'A';
    this.a = 'a';
  }
  
  getOuter() {
    console.log('outer');
    return `(${this.getInner()})`;
  }
  
  getInner() {
    console.log('a');
    return this.x + this.a;
  }
}

var a = new A

class Wrapper {
  constructor(original) {
    this.original = original
  }
  
  getOuter() {
    this.original.getInner = this.getInner.bind(this);
    return this.original.getOuter();
  }
  
  getInner() {
    delete this.original.getInner;
    return this.original.getInner();
  }
}

class B extends Wrapper {
  constructor(original) {
    super(original);
    this.x = 'B';
    this.b = 'b';
  }
  
  getInner() {
    console.log('b');
    return `[${this.x}${this.b}][${super.getInner()}]`;
  }
}

var b = new B(a);

class C extends Wrapper {
  constructor(original) {
    super(original);
    this.x = 'C';
    this.c = 'c';
  }
  
  getInner() {
    console.log('c');
    return `<${this.x}${this.c}><${super.getInner()}>`;
  }
}

var c = new C(b);

console.log(c.getOuter());
```

Comment: для чего это можно применять на практике в реальной жизни? или у вас просто учебный пример..

Comment: @spectre_it, кажется, с архитектурой накосячил... Не подумал, что вариант из вопроса не заработает, пока весь код не написал...